# File upload only works at my pc

Tags: php, html, file, upload

A few days ago I started designing a blog for my friend, he wanted to upload some images.

So this is a short version of the code, I used.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = @ end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        if (file_exists("../images/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../images/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This code works on my pc, but at friend's pc (he uses the same browser) it doesn't work.

Is there anywhere a mistake in my code or anyone know a better way to upload?

To be honest, this a temporary solution and I wanted to add stuff like upload progress bars, so if you also know a way to let it look cooler and more modern, I would really appreciate that.

Thanks you in anticipation!

Comment: What doesn't work? is he getting any error? how big are the files he is uploading? is he uploading the same files and types that you are?

Comment: There no error, actually. There jpgs are about 200kB big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great plugin http://www.uploadify.com/ that I've used before... however you have to pay for the HTML5 version of it.

http://www.plupload.com/ is another great plugin although its a bit more intense that Uploadify... HOWEVER, it is free and I believe its the plugin Wordpress actually uses as well.

Comment: looks pretty cool, but I haven't planned spending money for it :/

Comment: Well I wouldn't spend money on it really either LOL... especially since plupload is free. AND if you don't mind it not supporting iOS then uploadify is perfect because it uses flash lol... A cool think about plupload (which is free btw) is that you can fall back to different methods if not support. Example if flash isn't support you can fall back to silverlight, html5, chrome etc...

Comment: No problem-o.. I've been using plupload more and more... but I have a soft spot for uploadify... it was my first LOL :P

Comment: @Lumoris LOL thanks man.. idk if it answers your original question but since what you're doing is a temporary solution and what you want is a progress bar I figured I'd just go ahead and cut to the chase :P

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the answer format, but I cannot yet comment. What exactly does not work with your friends computer? For me, it seems to be functioning.